# Moving data from Azure Data Lake to another ADL belongs to different tenant using DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am moving the data from a Azure Data Lake to another Azure Data Lake Store that belongs to another subscription (tenant) using DataFactory.
I am getting error on uploading the LinkedService of Sink Data Lake like invalid credentials,
So Is it really possible actually what I am doing ? If it is,Kindly let me see some reference.

Comment: Are you using a service principal to authenticate or a session and token?

Comment: I tried both,I couldn't access through user auth as well as service principal

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @SiLaf I think not and I forget the issue as it happened an year ago

Comment: That's ok, but thanks for the response. Currently in talks with Azure support about this. If I solve the issue, I might give an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. For each data lake you need a separate service principal, each in the same subscription as the data lake. You can then create the two separate connections to the data lakes using each service principal.

You need both the service principal application ID and a key for it.

Note that the service principal not only needs access rights to the folder that you want to copy from or too, but also to the root folder of data lake.  I do not know if it also requires access rights to all directories between the root and the source/destination directory.

Note also that regardless of whether you are reading or writing data to this data lake, the service principal does need execute rights as well.

This isn't a complete answer, but just deals with the service principal side of the configuration to creating a connection. That is what gave me the most trouble.

Leave a comment if you feel more information would be useful

Answer (score -1):

If you have not read already, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector , Search for "Service principal authentication (recommended)". If you have already, I am presuming the error is because you have not provided the appropriate permissions for the entity to the ADLS folders. Without the exact error you are seeing, cannot say it is the source or the sink. In short can you provide more details of your context first and then what error you are seeing?

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager,
Azure Data Lake.